# SSRS Dynamic Gauges

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that has a collection of many gauges arranged in a grid.  The row of data that each gauges references is different based on the parameters used to run the report.  To accomplish this, I code each gauge individually to reference a specific row number from the data set.  For example, the gauge in "position" 1,1 (first row, first column) has references to "RowNumber" 1 and uses the lookup function to find the corresponding data needed to drive the gauge.  The gauge in "position" 1,2 has reference to "RowNumber" 2 and so and so on.

My question: is there a way to avoid hard coding these references?  For example, this is the label expression for the gauge in position 1,1:

```
=LOOKUP(1,fields!RowNumber.Value,fields!TestCase.Value,"main")
```

As you can see, the "1" is hardcoded.  I'm hoping to learn of a method where the expression would be more like:

```
=LOOKUP([gaugeReference!SomeAttribute],fields!RowNumber.Value,fields!TestCase.Value,"main")
```

...thus making all the expressions used inside the gauge *reusable*, no longer requiring hard coding.  I was initially hoping that I could name the gauges "1","2","3", etc. and then reference that name in the expression, meaning I would only need to change the *name* and then everything else would adjust automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just the row number you need (assumes the columns will always reference the same data based on their position) then it might be easier to create a dataset containing a record for each row for example

`SELECT 1 as RowNum UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4... UNION SELECT 10` etc.

You can then create a tablix with a single row based on this dataset and reference

`Fields!RownNum.Value`

Comment: Thank you!  This got me in the right direction and I finally figured it out.